# FastAPI list not showing?

Tags: python, fastapi

```
@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
# houses = json.load(open("data.json"))["houses"]["house"]
# return houses[0]["id"]

houses = json.load(open("data.json"))["houses"]["house"]
for house in houses:
    return house["id"]
```

When I run the commented code, I receive "3070", which is working as intended, however when I try to loop it in the non-commented code, I also receive "3070" instead of a list of ids.

Can't figure this one out, thanks for the help :)

Comment: the first execution of the `return` statement ends the code which means it should be outside the `for..loop`

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement ends the loop and the function. Your loop is correct but it will stop at the first element because of `return`. This is probably what you want:

```py
houses = []
for house in json.load(open("data.json"))["houses"]["house"]:
  houses.append(house["id"])

return houses
```

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, IT WORKED PERFECTLY !! Many thanks